# A type to which everything can be converted to?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, c++14, type-traits

I there a type `T` in C++14 such that `std::is_convertible<T, X>::value` returns `true` for all possible `X`?

Comment: Do you want the meta-function to always return true, or the type to actually produce valid objects for any X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can define `class B {~B() = delete;}`;

We can conclude that, for any given type T, there always exist at least one type X to which T can not be converted.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly make one yourself:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
  template <class T>
  operator T();
};

int main() 
{
  struct Bar{};
  static_assert(std::is_convertible<Foo, int>::value, "");
  static_assert(std::is_convertible<Foo, std::string>::value, "");
  static_assert(std::is_convertible<Foo, Bar>::value, "");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: beat me to it. In C++17 there is std::any, but it is more limited

Comment: Convertible to everything! Just don't try to actually do the conversion ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller possible to implement with trivial types, but not with classes that have vtable, that would be an UB  factory

Comment: @felix Except this is not possible because there are no void instances.

Comment: @Swift - Nothing is undefined with that implementation if the classes have an appropriate constructor. And it will be a hard compilation error, no UB in sight, when it fails.

Comment: Found another exception.. `class B {~B(){}};`

Comment: @StoryTeller oh but that would be a harder limit on classes that can be stored. I thought of  doing copy of storage, like some memory pool may do. Or there should be template specialization for each case.. for trivial classes, for non-trivial with copy constructor, for  simple types, etc.

Comment: @Swift - Your first idea enforces just as hard if not harder of a requirement on those classes, it just does so implicitly and with no protection from the type system.

Comment: @StoryTeller  implicitly - pun not intended? Alas, that's fair enough

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is for the meta-function to always return true, say because you are writing some super duper meta-function and need a placeholder for some Boolean logic, then I'd just sin and specialize the template:

```
struct everything {};

namespace std {
    template<typename X>
    struct is_convertible<everything, X> : true_type {};
};
```

Although, admittedly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046821/817643) accomplishes this much better, since it doesn't break into the `std` namespace and starts vandalizing templates.

Otherwise, no, there is no such type. At least no type that will produce valid objects for you.